# Windows and ubuntu won't boot due to kernel error

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, kernel

I have an acer laptop(AMD Processor) with dual boot configuration of windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I tried booting windows 10 last night and i got blue screen with kernel security check failure. Till now i have tried restarting multiple times and i got different errors like : ATTEMPTED TO WRITE TO READONLY MEMORY, PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA, IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL. Its the same with ubuntu, i get kernel panic not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt on boot.

1. I have tried using different kernel versions for ubuntu, doesn't work.
2. I tried going into safe mode using F8 key, nothing happens. Ubuntu's 
   recovery mode also gives kernel error.
3. I have done memtest, it passed.
4. I tried booting Ubuntu 17.10 using USB, it still gives me kernel error.

I haven't done any recent updates in windows or Ubuntu. The most i did was clean install new AMD graphic drives and multiple Vulkan api installs, a week ago.

Do you i have any suggestions what else can i try, or if the problem is most likely the hardware. What should i look into hardware wise?

Comment: Which memtest? One in your BIOS or the memtest which is usually in Linux boot menus?

Comment: The one in Grub menu, memtest86+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it looks indeed like a hardware (or firmware) issue, I would start by taking out the graphics card.

Also, any changes on BIOS? maybe default it?

For memory testing the easiest and fastest is taking them out and use just one.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was indeed memory issue. My laptop has 2 2GB ram sticks. I tried one stick at a time and it booted on BOTH times. Though on first stick it crashed 2 times, again giving blue screen error so i think this one is the culprit. I tried both stick same time but still won't start on them. So does this mean i can still fix it or i should replace the RAM. I appreciate your time :)

Comment: I wouldn't know how to fix it... Unfortunately, if it happened to me, I would change the stick... Sorry about that!